# sequence of curves that converges uniformly to a regular curve

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I am studying differential geometry and came across this exercise in the isoperimetric inequality section:

> *Let $\alpha$ be a regular curve and let {$\alpha_n$} be a succession of curves (defined in the same interval) that converges uniformly to $\alpha$. Show that $lim_{r \to \infty} inf \ \iota(\alpha_n) \geq \iota(\alpha)$*.

The truth is that I can't figure out how to start the problem. It is clear that I must use the fact of uniform convergence, but I don't know how to relate it to the length of the curve. Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: What's $\iota$?

Comment: Hard to be specific without an explanation of the notation, but you know that integration commutes with taking uniform limits...? (Here, the definition of _uniformly convergent_ for a sequence of regular paths needs careful attention; probably it involves derivatives/velocities as well as positions.)

Comment: $\iota$ is the length of the curve

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I did not know that! I will try to approach it knowing that, thanks.

Comment: It should be $\lim \inf$ instead of $\lim$

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Let the interval be $[0,2\pi].$ Define $\alpha(t)=(t,0).$ For $n$ odd, let $\alpha_n = \alpha.$ For $n$ even, let $\alpha_n(t)=(t,(\sin(nt))/n).$ Then $\alpha_n\to \alpha$ uniformly on $[0,2\pi].$

For $n$ odd we have $l(\alpha_n)=2\pi=l(\alpha).$ But for $n$ even we have

$$l(\alpha_n) = \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt {1+\cos^2(nt)}\,dt = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi n}\sqrt {1+\cos^2(s)}\,ds$$ $$ = \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt {1+\cos^2(s)}\,ds > \int_0^{2\pi}1\,ds =2\pi.$$

Comment: the correct statement should be with $\lim \inf$

Comment: @orangeskid you are right, i will correct it

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach.

We have the distance on the Riemannian manifold. Then we show that the length of any piecewise $C^1$ curve is given by $\sup \sum_i d(\gamma(t_i, t_{i+1})$ where $(t_i)$ is a division of the domain of the curve $\gamma$ ( like it happens for curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Once we have this, the inequality with $\lim \inf$ is fairly simple.